# In WPF, how to make thread-created Windows show again

Tags: wpf, multithreading

I created a MainWindow in the main thread, and there was a button in the MainWindow. When the button was clicked, a thread was created, and the thread created a NewWindow, NewWindow. But when I closed NewWindow, I clicked the button of the MainWindow again, and could not enter the function executed by the thread. I want to know exactly what to do to make NewWindow show when I press the button again.

```
namespace WpfApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private bool Restart;
        private Thread WindowThread;
        private SecondWindow NewWindow;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        private void LaunchWindow()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (Restart)
                {
                    if (ExportWindow == null)
                    {
                        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(
                            new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(
                            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher));

                        NewWindow = new SecondWindow();
                        NewWindow.Closing += (s, e) =>
                        {
                            Hide();
                            e.Cancel = true;
                        };

                        NewWindow.Closed += (s, e) =>
                        {
                            Dispatcher.ExitAllFrames();
                        };
                    }

                    Restart = false;
                    ExportWindow.Show();
                    Dispatcher.Run();
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void OnNewClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (WindowThread == null)
            {
                WindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LaunchWindow));
                WindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                WindowThread.IsBackground = true;
                WindowThread.Start();
            }

            Restart = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why on earth you open second window in another thread?

Comment: Because I was developing a plug-in for Revit, the WPF window would stop responding when Revit was running a long, time-consuming task. So I used a single thread to create the window, and the WPF window kept up to date even when Revit was running time-consuming tasks. But after the window closes, the thread can no longer execute. Above is a test demo I did

Comment: I see. IMHO, it can be accomplished easier by async/await programming model. That said, regarding your code, where is the field for NewWindow?

Comment: But I want to know why the thread cannot execute after NewWindow is closed. Because thread creation is expensive, I don't want to create a new thread every time, I want to use reusable threads whenever possible.

Comment: In [Task asynchronous programming model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model), usually a thread in thread pool will be used and new thread will not be created each time. That said, your code seems incomplete.